# How to get list of all files from OneDrive Business using c# Rest API?

Tags: c#, onedrive, office365-restapi

I want all files available on OneDrive Business.
[I am referring OneDrive v2 api..](https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm)
I want to display this list of files in my application.
Also is there any way I can filter files by type like photos,videos,documents?

Answer (score 0):

The OneDrive REST doesn’t return the descendants of collection, we need to iterate each folder to show the children of folders. And you can refer to [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/list.htm) to list the children of one item.

> > Also is there any way I can filter files by type like photos,videos,documents?

Yes. Items have Facets that provide data about the item's identities and capabilities. Folders have a folder facet and files have a file facet. Images have an image facet in addition to their file facet. So we can use these facets to restrict the file type we wanted.

For example, below is an example of filtering search results for only items that have a **file** and **image** facet.

**Request:**

```
GET /drive/root/view.search?q=vacation&filter=image%20ne%20null%20and%20file%20ne%20null
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: length

{
    "value": [
      {
        "id": "0123456789abc!123",
        "name": "Vacation.jpg",
        "image": { },
        "file": { },
        "searchResult":
        {
          "onClickTelemetryUrl": "https://bing.com/0123456789abc!123"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "0123456789abc!456",
        "name": "Summer.jpg",
        "image": { },
        "file": { },
        "searchResult":
        {
          "onClickTelemetryUrl": "https://bing.com/0123456789abc!456"
        }
      }
    ],
    "@search.approximateCount": 12,
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://api.onedrive.com/drive/root/view.search?query=vacation&skipToken=1asdlnjnkj1nalkm!asd"
}
```